# Bootstrap 3: Fixed Right Sidebar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I using one of the Bootstrap 3 [example](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/offcanvas/#) to build a sidebar. It works fine. But how can fix its position like navigation bar so that I won't loose it while scrolling down.
I tried adding `.uploadSideBar` class to `<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 sidebar-offcanvas sidebar-nav-fixed uploadSideBar"` like this

```
.uploadSideBar {
    margin-top:117px;
    postion:fixed
}
```

But it did not work.

Comment: Your problem was just a typo in the position property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're using the wrong selector. Use this one instead, I've tested it on the link you gave and it works:

```
.well.sidebar-nav {
position: fixed;
}
```